# How declare a variable inside a procedure MYSQL

Tags: mysql, function, stored-procedures

I'm trying to do an easy procedure inside my MySQL:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `countRows`(IN v varchar(30))
    BEGIN
    DECLARE e INT DEFAULT 0;
    SET @t1 =CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ",V, " INTO",e);
    PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
    EXECUTE stmt3;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
    SELECT CONCAT("The ",V," table contains ",e," rows");
   END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

EDIT: Everything works properly but @t1 doesn't save the value in the variable so that makes the second query to show 0 by default always.

I can't see any syntax error, some advices for make this work please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the statement in `@t2`; no need of a prepared statement since it doesn't contain any SQL statement to execute. The below mentioned 3 code lines are unnecessary.

```
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t2;
EXECUTE stmt3;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
```

You can simply display it like

```
SET @t2 =CONCAT("The ",V," table contains ",e," rows");
SELECT @t2;
```

(OR) Just

```
SELECT CONCAT("The ",V," table contains ",e," rows");
```

With that, your procedure should look like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `countRows`(IN v varchar(30))
BEGIN
DECLARE e INT DEFAULT 0;
SET @t1 =CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ",V, " INTO",e);
SET @t2 =CONCAT("The ",V," table contains ",e," rows");
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
EXECUTE stmt3;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
SELECT @t2;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT:**

Try like this once using user defined variable (procedure body below)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `countRows`(IN v varchar(30))
    BEGIN
    SET @e := 0;
    SET @t1 =CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @e FROM ",V);
    PREPARE stmt3 FROM @t1;
    EXECUTE stmt3;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
    SELECT CONCAT("The ",V," table contains ",@e," rows");
   END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I'm editing my question. All works but @t1 doesn't save the value of the query in the e variable it is always 0 (by default)

Comment: Do you really have records in your table? check once.

Comment: Now is finally working as expected! Why this only works with global variables?

Comment: There seems to be a bug with prepared statement in MySQL; AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Since, as you noted, you declared the variable `e` within the stored procedure it does not exist outside of that environment.

I think the issue lies here:

`SET @t1 =CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  ",V, " INTO e");`

try changing this to:

`SET @t1 =CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  ",V, " INTO",e);`